# Parser error, symbols undefined in mips program

Tags: mips

I keep getting this error:

```
spim: (parser) parse error on line 26 of file jc4137.s
  li    $t0, $a0 # t0 = str
           ^
The following symbols are undefined:
main
t
```

I was wondering what this is?

The chunk of code is this:

```
ispalindrome:
    li      $v0, 0
    li      $s0, 0 # length of str
    li      $t0, $a0 # t0 = str
```

Comment: The purpose of `li` is to load immediates. `$a0` is a register, not an immediate, so you should be using `move $t0,$a0` instead. You also appear to have forgotten to declare `main` as global.

Comment: I see. I fixed the code to become move $t0, $a0, and both errors went away. Thanks Michael.